# Displaying results based on when the report is printed

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating an Oracle Report and I would like to display certain results based on when I print the report. There is a field called apply_date. For example, if I print the report <= sysdate of 3/15 then I only want to display the records that have an apply_date of 3/1 - 3/15. This also goes for printing on the 30th of each month. If I print the report after 3/15 then it would only show me the results that have an apply_date of >= 3/16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `where` clause such as this:

```
where (to_char(sysdate, 'DD') <= '15' and
       to_char(apply_date, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM') and
       to_char(apply_date, 'DD') between '00' and '15'
      ) or
      (to_char(sysdate, 'DD') >= '16' and
       to_char(apply_date, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM') and
       to_char(apply_date, 'DD') >= '16'
      )
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much for your help. I've been killing my brain trying to figure this out. I knew I could put an 'or' in there somehow, but just wasn't sure how.

Comment: @user2188170 . . . Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hmmm, not very index or optimiser friendly, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the best use of indexes and to give the optimiser the best estimate of cardinality I'd try to build the SQL so that the predicate does not rely on functions applied to the apply_date:

```
 where apply_date >= case
                     when extract(day from sysdate) < 16
                     then trunc(sysdate,'MM')
                     else trunc(sysdate,'MM')+16
                     end
   and apply_date <  case
                     when extract(day from sysdate) >= 16
                     then add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1)
                     else trunc(sysdate,'MM')+16
                     end
```

On execution the R.H.S. of the predicates will be transformed to:

```
 where apply_date >= <date>
   and apply_date <  <date>
```